# How to disable Email requirement - Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

Hello I hope you are doing well
can you help me to disable the Email requirement in the Checkout page for guests (not logged in) in Magento 2.4.3

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify these things.

1. First, Check this file available in your custom theme.

> app/design/frontend/[THEME]/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/form/element/email.html

2. Second, Check the same file override into any custom extension.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/form/element/email.html

3. Third, it calls from default Magento, So you need to override the same file either into your theme or any custom extension and then make changes to that.